# VBA ACCESS - SQL statement which Counting between 2 columns which are variables

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I need a macro in VBA Access. I have a table with all dates of the years like columns (and also the dates are the names of the fields). I've made a form where the user selects two dates, and the macro would count all the data between these 2 columns.

For the example, I put two fixed dates. The problem is I need count between the 2 columns, and the columns can change depending the input of the user. The table is EVOLUTIVO_ASISTENCIA and the field can change depends the user selection. Ihe following code EVOLUTIVO_ASISTENCIA.[" & INICIO_MES_VAR1 & "] is the field "01-01-2023" of the EVOLUTIVO_ASISTENCIA table, but the syntax is wrong and does not function. Can anyone help me?

The code:

```
Private Sub BUSQUEDA()

Dim CONTEO As String
Dim VAR1 As String
Dim INICIO_MES_VAR1 As Date, TERMINOS_MES_VAR1 As Date

INICIO_MES_VAR1 = Format("01-01-2023", "dd-mm-yyyy")
TERMINOS_MES_VAR1 = Format("31-01-2023", "dd-mm-yyyy")

VAR1 = "VAR1"


             CONTEO = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EVOLUTIVO_ASISTENCIA " & _
                         "WHERE EVOLUTIVO_ASISTENCIA.[NOMBRES]='" & VAR1 & "' " & _
                        ** "BETWEEN EVOLUTIVO_ASISTENCIA.[" & INICIO_MES_VAR1 & "] AND EVOLUTIVO_ASISTENCIA.[" & TERMINOS_MES_VAR1 & "]"**
                             DoCmd.RunSQL CONTEO
                                
                                  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't *run* a select query, you *open* it as a recordset. So try:

```vb
Private Sub BUSQUEDA()

    Dim Records             As DAO.Recordset

    Dim CONTEO              As String
    Dim VAR1                As String
    Dim INICIO_MES_VAR1     As String
    Dim TERMINOS_MES_VAR1   As String
    Dim ASISTENCIA_CONTEO   As Long

    INICIO_MES_VAR1 = "01-01-2023"
    TERMINOS_MES_VAR1 = "31-01-2023"
    VAR1 = "VAR1"

    CONTEO = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EVOLUTIVO_ASISTENCIA " & _
        "WHERE EVOLUTIVO_ASISTENCIA.[NOMBRES]='" & VAR1 & "' " & _
        "BETWEEN EVOLUTIVO_ASISTENCIA.[" & INICIO_MES_VAR1 & "] AND EVOLUTIVO_ASISTENCIA.[" & TERMINOS_MES_VAR1 & "]"

    Set Records = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(CONTEO)

    ' Read/list/print records.
    ' Retrieve the value of the first and only field of the first and only record.
    ASISTENCIA_CONTEO = Records(0).Value
    ' Close when done.
    Records.Close
                                
End Sub
```